# How to use pyzmq to communicate between parent process and child process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, parent-child, zeromq, pyzmq

I am creating a child process using python multiprocessing. Parent will be creating a socket as zmq.PUB. Child will be subscribing to that socket. But the problem is child is not receiving any message.

This code is working in windows. But, when I try with RHEL 7.5, it is not working.

```
import multiprocessing
import zmq
import os
import time

port = '5555'


def child():
    print("Child pid: ", os.getpid())
    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, str.encode(''))
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
    socks = dict(poller.poll())
    while (True):
        for key, value in socks.items():
            print(key, " ", value)
        time.sleep(5)
        print('receiving data')
        if socket in socks and socks[socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
            try:
                string = socket.recv_string(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
            except (zmq.error.Again, Exception) as e:
                break
        print('data received: ', string)


def main():
    print("Parent pid: ", os.getpid())
    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
    childproc = multiprocessing.Process(name='childproc',target=child)
    childproc.daemon = False
    childproc.start()
    while (True):
        print('data publishing')
        socket.send_string("hello")
        time.sleep(5)
```

In windows the result is:

```
Parent pid:  5536
data publishing
Child pid:  13964
data publishing
<zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object at 0x000001E5BB6B3BA8>   1
data publishing
receiving data
data received:  hello
<zmq.sugar.socket.Socket object at 0x000001E5BB6B3BA8>   1
data publishing
receiving data
data received:  hello
......
......
```

In Linux the output is:

```
Parent pid:  21850
data publishing
Child pid:  21854
data publishing
data publishing
data publishing
data publishing
data publishing
data publishing
data publishing
..........
..........
```

Is it the problem with using PUB/SUB?
How can I use ZMQ for this parent to child communication?
If ZMQ does not support this, which other library can be used instead?
If I use queue and pipes from multiprocessing module, What possible problems are there, If the messages are JSON objects?

Comment: the PUB / SUB pattern is a slow joiner, meaning you need to wait a while after binding the PUB socket and before sending any message.

Comment: @Yaourtide That is not causing this behaviour, I suppose. Slow joiner will make the child to lose first message right? But, it can receive messages later on.

Comment: No slow joiner in zmq pub / sub patterns will cause the sub socket to receive no message at all

Comment: @Yaourtide If that is the case, how is the same code working in windows?

Comment: Okay I'll clarify. My assumption are valid for C++ under Linux. I've never used ZMQ under Windows so I don't actually know if there's a difference (could be). That's why I didn't formulated an answer because i'm not actually sure. But the first thing I would check would be to wait before sending the first message and see if that fix the problem. Otherwise you may have another issue

Comment: I will add a delay of 5 secs and try.

Comment: I added a delay of 5secs outside the while loop for parent. But, it is still not working. The point is, the poller of child is blocking as it is not receiving any messages. I dont know much about how to debug this.

Comment: Try reading this [link](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html), you also have example [here](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/examples/pubsub). 
I don't have a computer to reproduce it at the moment.